# How to change values of sliced tensorflow object

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, yolo

I wanted to write a custom loss function to my tensorflow keras model that will perform the YOLO algorithm, the problem was when there wasn't a object in a specific grid, the derivative of the location of the object should be 0 because it shouldn't care about it.
So I tried to multiply it by y_true for each bbox but I couldn't slice the Tensor object and change its values.

def YOLO_loss_function_shell(classes_path, output_shape):
    with open(classes_path, "r") as f_arch:
        classes = list(map(lambda row: row.strip("\n").strip("\r"),
                                f_arch.readlines()))
    classes = list(filter(lambda row: row != "" and not row.startswith("#"), classes))
    num_classes = len(classes)
    bbox_size = (5 + num_classes)
    num_bboxes = int(output_shape[2] / bbox_size)

```
def YOLO_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    cost = np.subtract(np.multiply(-y_true, 
                                  (K.log(y_pred + tf.keras.backend.epsilon()))),
                np.multiply((1 - y_true),
                            (K.log(1 - y_pred + tf.keras.backend.epsilon()))))
    for b in range(num_bboxes):
        cost[:, :, bbox_size*b:bbox_size*(b + 1)] *= y_true[:, :, bbox_size*b:(bbox_size*b + 1)]

    return K.sum(cost, axis=-1)

return YOLO_loss_function
```

And it keeps telling me 
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment